# Android - View be shrink when load from memory

Tags: android

I have a list view with difference item layouts.

First I inflated the view and store it memory.
When the list view get the child view (from getChildView function)) I will return the in-memory object. Everything seems ok except when I scroll the list, the view is shrink to 2/3 original size and after that it become bigger (fullsize).

I hope that is an animation of android OS but still not found the solution now.

The reason why I need to load it from memory is the inflate function take a lot of time (~100 miliseconds on HTC desire) and make the scrolling does not smooth (lag)

Have you meet this?

I tested on android version: 2.0 and 2.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mentioned it in your question, but do you use `convertView` parameter in the `getView()` method of the list adapter? You shouldn't inflate view on every `getView()` call, because `ListView` class has a special view recycle bin for storing inflated views. You can get some explanations from [this video](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wDBM6wVEO70).

Comment: yes, I used convert view as well as watched the video :) <br /> However as you see, my list (expandable list) contains several kinds of layout (xml files) It works perfect if my list just contain the Aksjer part.

Comment: I dont know how the google cache the view but They has introduced android.widget.HeterogeneousExpandableList interface for this kind of requirement but from API 8 (while I have to live with API 5)

Comment: I cant not have a right solution now. but There's away to work around: pre-inflate them in another thread.

Comment: I noticed that not only the view but also other GUI component such as Drawable. If you reuse it, you must call invalidateSeft() otherwise, the shrink issue appear.